# how to CSS select all th cells, except the last one on IE7/8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I'm trying to fit some CSS to also work on IE7 and IE8 and I'm stuck with the :not() selector.

I need to select all table header cells except the last one. I'm currently using this:

```
 th:not(:last-child)
```

which fails on IE7+8.

Are there any CSS only workarounds?

Thanks for some hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you ask it:

> all table header cells except the last one

could refer to:

- the last `th` of the table, wherever it could be found,
- the last element of a row (presumably the last one of `thead>tr` - and there could be more than one `tr` there),
- the last `th` in each row.

None of these cases can be solved by CSS understood by IE7/8 (resp. no solution in CSS at all, `th:last-child` and `th:last-of-type`)

EDIT: in one case, there could be a solution. If you exactly know how many `th` elements there are in each row then you can select say the fourth one with `th ~ th ~ th ~ th`.
See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector for IE7/8 bugs (no comment allowed).
It's up to you to modify this selector if there are only `th` in a row (the `+` selector would be OK too) or if there are `@colspan` or `@rowspan` attributes (number of elements in a row != number of columns).

Comment: you are correct, I could have been more specific. It actually is the last th cell in a thead with multiple rows, alas *thead th:not(:last-child)*.

Comment: ah. never heard of ~. Cool. Let's try

Comment: @frequent That was the most probable :) but yes it's harder to explain these things in writings than to a colleague with help of sight and finger on screen. :) BTW please see my edit, one case can be solved by CSS only

Comment: yes I saw that. This is actually a handy solution. And works for my case. One more :not down, still plenty to solve. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it only by adding extra class for last elements in code generator. No tool for IE8,7 and older.

Comment: hm. that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

You can't  do it with pure `css`. You can give class to your last `th` in your HTML or you can use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) JavaScript for this. Selectivizr support all css3 & css2 selectors for IE older version